# How to dynamically adjust the page margins according to the header / footer height

Tags: java, itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I'm using iText and pdfHtml to convert HTML pages to PDF.

Though I'm having trouble getting each page to adjust to it's specific header or footer.

**Some of the headers / footers I'm using are taller than others**, thus the content needs to start further down.

To get the headers / footers onto the page **I'm using an event handler that** generates a `PdfXObject` for each required header / footer and **pastes it onto the page** using a `PdfCanvas`.

However, since the headers and footers are not really part of the page content, **iText doesn't know how much space they require**.

It seems that you can only set the page margins once. Either by using the `@page` rule and `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()` or by using `Document.setMargins()` when using `HtmlConverter.convertToElements()`. You can technically specify one more specific margin for the first page using `@page:first`, but that's not really all that useful if page 2 uses a different header than page 3.

**Is there any way of adjusting the page margins to the header / footer of each individual page?**

Also, **maybe pasting them onto the finished page isn't the best practice either**, please do tell me if so.

Cheers
--Zuzu_Typ--